# How to rearrange the entries (character) in each row of a dataframe according to the alphabetical order?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
df=data.frame(word1 = c("hello", "red", "red"), word2 = c("world", "hello", "yellow"), word3 = 
                   c("red", "world", "hello"), n = c(574L, 306L, 302L))
```

i.e.

```
> df
  word1  word2 word3   n
1 hello  world   red 574
2   red  hello world 306
3   red yellow hello 302
```

I would like to rearrange the words in each row according to the alphabetical order. For example:

```
> df_new
  word1 word2 word3    n
1 hello   red world  574
2 hello   red world  306
3 hello   red yellow 302
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the rows with `apply` on the selected column, `sort` and update those columns

```
df[1:3] <- t(apply(df[1:3], 1, sort))
```

---

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   transmute(out = list(sort(c_across(where(is.character)))), n) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   unnest_wider(c(out), names_repair =  ~names(df))
```